# inserting node in a linklist using java

Tags: java, data-structures

I m beginner at java. I am trying to implement simple linklist structure using java.

I have written following code that inserts node at the end of the linklist.

```
 public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
    if(head == null)
    {
      Node temp = new Node(data);
        head = temp;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
         Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current = temp;
    return head;
    }
}
```

The Node class is defined as follows

```
class Node {
int data;
Node next;
Node(int d) {
    data = d;
    next = null;
}
}
```

The class LinkListDemo has the insert(),display() and main() method as follows..

```
 class LinkListDemo
 {
 public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
    if(head == null)
    {
      Node temp = new Node(data);
        head = temp;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
         Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null)
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    current = temp;
    return head;
    }
}
public static void display(Node head) {
    Node start = head;
    while(start != null) {
        System.out.print(start.data + " ");
        start = start.next;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node head = null;
    int N = sc.nextInt();

    while(N-- > 0) {
        int ele = sc.nextInt();
        head = insert(head,ele);
    }
    display(head);
    sc.close();
}
}
```

INPUT: 4 2 3 4 1

I gave input as 4(number of nodes to be inserted) 2 3 4 1(corresponding node values)

I expected output to be 2 3 4 1
but the output is only 2.

Please help me to correct my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `else` part of your insert method. You are looping till `current` becomes null and then assign the new node `temp` to it. Assigning the reference to the new node(`temp`) will not append (or link) to the end of the list.

The correct way is to go to the **last** node and then link the new node i.e, make the last node's next point to the new node.

It should be like

```
while(current.next != null) {
    current = current.next;
}
current.next = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code for insert(), you should have

```
while(current.next != null)
{
    current = current.next;
}
```

In your code, your current variable will always end up being null, resulting in your node not actually being inserted. This fix makes your current variable the last node in the list, so that you can set the last node's pointer to your new node.

Answer (score 0):

I am inserting node using following code

```
public void addFirst(int e) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new LinkListNode(e);
            tail = head;
            size = 1;
        } else {
            LinkListNode nextNode = new LinkListNode(e);
            nextNode.setNext(head);
            head = nextNode;
            size++;
        }
    }
```

Working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just Change little bit code

```
Node current = head;
while(current.next != null)
{
    current = current.next;
}
current.next= temp;
```

and return head